# Mysql is not runing alone, but runing in lampp/xampp

Tags: mysql, php, web-development

i just started webdevelopment on ubuntu in core php and laravel Framework. I have installed php and all the dependencies but **mysql is not working indiviually but  its working inside lampp**

so i began with giving the following command

mysql -u root -p

and the i get the following response(same for runing only 'mysql' and 'sudo mysql')

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Also when i go to /var/run there is no folder with the name mysqld

```
cd /var/run/mysqld
bash: cd: /var/run/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

See this too

```
cd /var/run 
aq@DevilsBook:/var/run$ ls
acpid.pid     console-setup  dhclient-wlo1.pid  initctl      mount           rsyslogd.pid       sudo        user
acpid.socket  crond.pid      dmeventd-client    initramfs    network         sendsigs.omit.d    systemd     utmp
alsa          crond.reboot   dmeventd-server    lock         NetworkManager  shm                thermald    uuidd
apache2       cryptsetup     fsck               log          php             snapd-snap.socket  tmpfiles.d  wpa_supplicant
avahi-daemon  cups           gdm3               lvm          plymouth        snapd.socket       udev
blkid         dbus           gdm3.pid           lvmetad.pid  pppconfig       spice-vdagentd     udisks2
```

Other then That there is a folder named mysql and mysql-upgrade in /var/lib..

Then i tried the **service mysql start** command and it took so much time

```
sudo service mysql status
[sudo] password for aq: 
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; bad; vendor preset: enable
   Active: inactive (dead)

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo service mysql status
```

and run the **same comand without sudo** and i get

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After that i see **systemctl status mysql.service** and the result was

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; bad; vendor preset: enable
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-15 01:04:13 PKT; 28s ago
  Process: 3359 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit

جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time ov
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, r
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated t
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
lines 1-11/11 (END)...skipping...
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-15 01:04:13 PKT; 28s ago
  Process: 3359 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~



[2]+  Stopped                 systemctl status mysql.service
```

At the end i ran **journalctl -xe**

```
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
جنوری 15 01:04:13 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
جنوری 15 01:05:29 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
جنوری 15 01:05:30 DevilsBook systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
```

Even though mysql is working in lamp see the result of lampp runing **sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start**

```
aq@DevilsBook:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
[sudo] password for aq: 
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.13-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

**How do i locate the folder and the package to eliminiate this issue ??**

Comment: Are mysql / mysqld running at all ?

Comment: I dont think so, because when i login into mysql using terminal it give the first error message mentioned in the question

Comment: Just checked again and it says
mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1109591/edit) your question with including the output of `sudo service mysql status`

Answer (score 1):

Answer from ->> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qr-t8ksYO78

go to my.cnf file, note that you will find multiple my.cnf file, i had to look at all of them to find this->

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Copy the path and write it like ->

```
mysql -u root -p --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Thanks